# Check if a object value is greater then 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have multiple inputs (type="number") and when someone put a value into it i am creating a object. I like to create a statement and check if a specific object value is greater then 0.

```
if(el){
   el.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
     const input = evt.target
     if (input.checked || input.value.length) {
        steps[input.dataset.name] = {
        value: input.value
        }
        } else {
         delete steps[input.dataset.name]
         }                
      })
  }
```

So my object i looking like that
[image]

So in object steps i have multiple objects where each has a unique name and a value. I like to run a function but only when a specific object value is greater then 0, in example when sale_monthly_additional_sales value is > 0 do something. I have no idea how to even start with that.

Comment: You can get the keys which have a value greater than 0 by using a simple filter on the object keys.  Say your object is in a variable called data:


Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].value > 0);


you can then iterate over these and 'do-stuff'

Answer (score 0):

you could add condition like that.

1. Create array and add key name of the element name .
2. Then match with [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).Finally apply you condition as you wish

**CODE**

```
var arr =['sale_monthly_additional_sales']; //
if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    const input = evt.target
    if (input.checked || input.value.length) {
    var val =input.value; // initiate default value
    if(arr.includes(input.dataset.name)){ //match keyname  on your element name
      val = parseFloat(input.value) > 0 ?'your code':val; //over write as you condition
    }
      steps[input.dataset.name] = {
        value: input.value
      }
    } else {
      delete steps[input.dataset.name]
    }
  })
}
```